# Xamarin not respects JDK location (VS2015)

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I can't build Xamarin application in Visual studio 2015 because Xamarin ignores configured JDK location. I configured Xamarin to use JDK 1.8:

[image]

But the build still fails because it is using old JDK that I removed from machine: jdk1.7.0_79

```
9>_ResolveMonoAndroidSdks: 

9>  MonoAndroid Tools: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\ 

9>  MonoAndroid Binaries: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\ 

9>  Android Platform API level: 24 

9>  TargetFrameworkVersion: v6.0 

9>  Android NDK: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e\ 

9>  Android SDK: c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\ 

9>  Android SDK Build Tools: c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\ 

9>  **Java SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\**
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: Try uninstalling JDK 1.7

Comment: That is what I did, and that is why it can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the answer: during build process xamarin produces bunch of `sdk.cache` files with old location and then reuses them.

More information: http://the-coderok.azurewebsites.net/2016/07/29/What-to-do-when-Xamarin-ignores-configured-JDK-location-Or-unable-to-change-JDK-location-for-Xamarin/

Comment: Interesting. If anything nuking your `bin/obj` folders would resolve this as well.