# Xamarin - Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to create an app with Material Design using Xamarin and Visual Studio. I want to achieve this using the v7 AppCompat library, so my app runs well on older devices.

I followed this tutorial:

https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-material-design-v7-appcompat/

and did exact the same. When I go to the `Main.axml` file(in the `Resources/layout` folder) there's a dropdown menu where you can select a theme(picture below). However, when I open the dropdown menu, my theme doesn't appear. So I thought it was a good idea to clean and rebuild my project. But when I cleaned the project, I got this error:

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
```

How can I fix it and make my theme appear in the dropdown menu?

EDIT:

Here's the code:

`Main.axml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/MyButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`values/styles.xml`

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

`values-v21`

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

`MainActivity.cs`

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace MaterialDesign
{
    [Activity(Label = "MaterialDesign", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE:

Also when I am using the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` element, I got the following error: `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar element is not declared`.

EDIT(2):

I tried downloading it with the component manager, with a NuGet command(Package Manager Console) and manually download the dll's and reference them, but it still didn't work.
I also removed the `\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.0.1.3` folder and removed the cache, but without succes.

And at the `Main.axml` file in the designer tab, appears a warning:

```
This project contains resources that were not compiled successfully,
rendering might be affected
```

I found out that the problem is with Visual Studio Designer, as it runs properly on my phone. So I asked a new question:[Xamarin.Android, Visual Studio - Designer doesn't work with v7 AppCompat library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056960/xamarin-android-visual-studio-designer-doesnt-work-with-v7-appcompat-library)

Here you can download my project:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxiDy9-wQHvzNFRhaTMzelg1WlU/view?usp=sharing

(Sorry for bad English, feel free to correct me)

Comment: For a better comprehension of the problem paste the code.

Comment: Where are you applying the theme? In your `AndroidManifest.xml`? Try to nuke the `bin/obj` folders, Clean your Project, and Rebuild. Please also ensure your `v7 AppCompat` NuGet package is referenced appropriately.

Comment: @JonDouglas I'm applying the theme in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. I nuked the `bin` and `obj` folders. I cleaned and rebuild my object. I got the same errors as before: `Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.`(more details at the top of my question). When I hit rebuild, I got this error: `1>  java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`(more details in the edit(2) section of my question). So unfortunately  it didn't work :(

Comment: For the `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` error try uninstalling your current JDK version and installing 1.8. If you keep getting errors, upload a sample project and edit your post with the link.

Comment: @JonDouglas no more errors when I rebuild the project, but still the same error when I clean my project.

Comment: @JonDouglas I added uploaded my project on Google Drive:(URL in question)

Comment: Your project builds and deploys just fine for me. Ensure you only have JDK 1.8 installed. Delete the bin/obj folders, and re-deploy your application. You can also try deleting the local cache of the `AppCompat` library. Also try to remove the respective support library found in these folders: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/#automatic

Comment: @JonDouglas what is the problem when I've JDK 1.7 installed? At the settings of Xamarin I selected JDK 1.8.

Comment: @qwertytrewq The problem can be that the Java 1.7 SDK is cached. See this answer to ensure it's not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670675/xamarin-not-respects-jdk-location-vs2015#comment64784577_38670675 Thus VS typically can pickup an old SDK cache location instead. Double check your Build Output to ensure it's not.

Comment: @JonDouglas Uninstalled JDK 1.7 and restarted, still the same error

Comment: Try adding the `android:` prefix to your resources in the original error. I'm testing this on Mac which may not validate this like VS does. https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette

Comment: @JonDouglas I can now select the theme at the theme dropdown menu, but if I select my theme, it doesn't show the phone mockup with a theme, just the `Hello World, Click Me!` text. And when I clean my project I get this error: `Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.`

Comment: @JonDouglas According to the tutorial, I don't have to use the `android:` prefix: `You will see that these attributes are different than using the standard Material Theme since they have dropped the android: prefix as they are now part of your application.`

Comment: @JonDouglas image for clarification: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxiDy9-wQHvzVnNTSnVpbWxhaEk/view?usp=sharing This is what I get when I use the `android:` prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had nothing to do with the code. It's just that Visual Studio at moment of writing doesn't support Custom Views.

Just use Xamarin Studio or this plugin https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9f5a516a-f4d0-4228-9d25-d0273abebf33 So you can edit your applications in Android Studio.

See [Xamarin.Android, Visual Studio - Designer doesn't work with v7 AppCompat library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056960/xamarin-android-visual-studio-designer-doesnt-work-with-v7-appcompat-library) for more detailed answers.