# Xamarin.Android, Visual Studio - Designer doesn't work with v7 AppCompat library

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, visual-studio-designer

I want to create an app with Material Design using Xamarin and Visual Studio. I want to achieve this using the v7 AppCompat library, so my app runs well on older devices.

I have an activity with a toolbar and a button.

But in the Visual Studio Designer the layout isn't as it's supposed to be(No Material theme and no Toolbar):

[image: Visual Studio Designer]

But the strange thing is that it runs properly on my phone(without any changes made):
[image: My phone]

How can I fix this?

Comment: As a work around, I use `Android Studio` to design Android layouts...

Comment: @SushiHangover That's actually not a bad idea! I'm gonna use that until I've got an answer

Comment: @SushiHangover How did you manage to get that working?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the VS Plugin as Jon Douglas included in his answer, I basically do the same thing without the plugin by including an actual Android Studio project into my solution tree and thus I can sync (git) changes between OS-X and Windows... By using `.csproj` <Link> items I can maintain both projects without a plugin or copy-based scripts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the Visual Studio Designer doesn't show Support Library elements.
You can use Xamarin Studio, which lately improved there Designer very much, and is easier to integrate with Visual Studio than Android Studio.
To download it go to http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Windows/XamarinStudio-6.0.2.73-0.msi (also available through your dashboard in [www.xamarin.com](http://xamarin.com) under downloads, different versions).

EDIT: Currently you need to change the Cycle to beta (Help -> Check for Updates)

Comment: That doesn't work, it doesn't show the layout properly.

Comment: @qwertytrewq Sorry, you need to change the cycle to a beta cycle. It works in the beta version.

Comment: @qwertytrewq To do that, click on help >> Check for Updates and change the cycle.

Comment: @qwertytrewq Your welcome. Please vote +1 if you think it's worth it ;)

Comment: I did! (sorry for this text between parenthesis but comments must be at least 15 characters)

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is slated to be released in our Cycle 8 release(XVS 4.2.0.378 at the time of writing) to support AAR / Custom Views. You can find a link about this here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.2/#Android_Designer

It should be released to Stable shortly. For a non-beta/alpha workaround, I would highly recommend using this VS plugin for the time being which combines using Android Studio and Visual Studio to be the most productive when designing:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9f5a516a-f4d0-4228-9d25-d0273abebf33

For a more accurate timeline of these changes, you can view the latest blog article on the Beta channel:

https://releases.xamarin.com/beta-preview-1-cycle-8/

Upcoming Release Dates

Alpha – April 27th, 2016 (Evolve Conference)

Alpha 2 – July 13th, 2016

Alpha 3 – July 27th, 2016

Alpha 4 – Aug 2nd, 2016

Alpha 5– Aug 9th, 2016

Alpha 6 – August 12, 2016

**Beta 1 – This Release!**

Stable – Fall 2016

Thus if you wanted this functionality in your IDE, you will need to use XVS 4.2.X + in either the Alpha/Beta channels as of the time of writing.